# Rails 3: Skip validation for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

It seems that in rails 3 (version 3.0.7) validates_associated is enabled by default (and as a result it is deprecated).

My model Payment has an associated model Reminder:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :reminder

end
```

whenever I create a new payment, it also validates the associated reminder. I want to skip this. Adding :validate => false to the relation didn't work. Any suggestions? And also if someone could tell about the changes in rails 3 w.r.t validates_associated, as I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a validation issue, but I was updating my Reminder model after creating the Payment entry. That resulted in the validations for Reminder model being triggered.

Added a condition for that special case (where I wanted to skip the validation) to not update the reminder model.

Even though the answer is specific to my scenario, but adding as it may be of help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why an association validation would be happening unless explicitly defined. Is there anything on your reminder that could be doing a check?

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.7/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.7/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: The Reminder model has a custom validation which validates that the due_date is not in the past, and it is failing when creating a new payment. I want to change this behaviour.